# Is there a way to see the uninstall history of an android device?

Tags: android

Just want to know how to track what applications a user has uninstalled from their device in the past.

Answer (score 1):

There is no log available that you can read way after the apps have been uninstalled *(afaik)*.

All you can do is listen for the [`ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) broadcast while your own app is installed. It contains the package name of an app that the user just uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

There is no record of that on the phone/device and even if there would be it would not be available to a non-root application.